# Change Calendar URL on select/change date

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

I have searched and read everything I could find on change / set url in datepicker, I tried and tried but I can not change the url of the calendar ...
**The situation:**
In modal window just by using CSS.
I have a form in a [modal CSS3 pupup](https://www.script-tutorials.com/css3-modal-popups/) in which I request the departure date and the end date.
I propose the minimum date and the maximum date and allow the user to change the dates.

**Problem**:
If the user invokes the calendar by clicking on the icon to change the date (minimum or maximum) and choose another date, modal window closes leaving the calendar active.
Instead I expect to close calendar and continue to manage the form fields in the modal window until the user click on the confirm button.

this is the modified script as I read:

```
    enter code here
from = $( "#from" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar_icon-32x32.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "From date",
    changeMonth: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function(mindata) {
        if (mindata != dalla_data) {
            dalla_data = mindata;
        };
        window.location.href = "http://index.php?ricid=1&modo=1&tiporic=2&prg=gesric#gesric_form" + this.value;
    }
}).on( "change", function() {
    to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
    display("Got change event from field");
}),
to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({ 
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar_icon-32x32.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    buttonText: "To date",
    onSelect: function(maxdata) {
        if (maxdata != alla_data) {
            alla_data = maxdata;
        };
        window.location.href = "http://index.php?ricid=1&modo=1&tiporic=2&prg=gesric#gesric_form" + this.value;
    }
}).on( "change", function() {
    from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
});

$("#from").datepicker('enable');
$("#to").datepicker('enable');

function getDate( element ) {
    var date;
    try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
    } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
    }

    return date;
}
```

But it does not work, and debugging on the calendar link remains:

```
<a class="ui-state-default ui-state-active" href="#">
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

ok, I solved
I cleaned the script and now it works.

```
$( function() {

from = $( "#from" ).datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "images/calendar_icon-32x32.png",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonText: "From date",
  changeMonth: true,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    }),

to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({ 
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "images/calendar_icon-32x32.png",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonText: "To date",
  changeMonth: true,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });

$("#from").datepicker('enable');
$("#to").datepicker('enable');

function getDate( element ) {
  var date;
  try {
    date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
  } catch( error ) {
    date = null;
  }
  return date;
}
```

} );